# SQLAlchemy - How can I copy rows from one table to another?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Let's say I have the following tables with the columns in parens:

- **fruits** (id, name, weight)
- **apples** (fruit_id, name, type)

I'm trying to copy only the data in the id and name columns from `fruits` into `apples`.

So far I have:

```
fruit_rows = Fruits.query.all()

for fruit_row in fruit_rows:
    apple_row = Apples(
        fruit_id=Fruits.id,
        name=Fruits.name,
    )
    session.merge(apple_row)


session.commit()
```

Am I on the right track here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fruit_rows = Fruits.query.all()

for fruit_row in fruit_rows:
    apple_row = Apples(
        fruit_id=fruit_row.id,
        name=fruit_row.name,
    )
    session.add(apple_row)


session.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks! Good to see I was pretty close.